# Qt - effects on no-opengl widgets

Tags: c++, qt

i wanna make some nice user interface, but still using just classic ui elements from Qt. 
For instance i have 2 forms and i wanna make some transition between them. For instance rotate  first ui screen and make it disappear. It's possible in some way to use shader? Is any way how to do complex ui animations with classic ui elements?

Answer (score 1):

Qt has a whole [animation framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/animation-overview.html). It works on both the QML widgets and for the classic UI elements that you're using. There's some examples of use [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtanimationframework/animation.html), that should be able to get you started.

Comment: but this way it looks i will need to manipulate each item, for instance rotate etc. Isn't there way how to process for instance currently rendered screen in my app?

Comment: You can apply the rotation directly onto a main container widget I believe (I haven't tested it), and it should cascade to any child widgets. There's some more information on QAnimation and the layout system here: http://blog.eduardofleury.com/archives/2009/02/51

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it would be to use the Qt Declarative a.k.a. Qt Quick 1. It's based on QGraphicsScene, with the latter offering a reasonable way of integrating legacy widgets. It'll be likely the simplest way to offer animations with widgets.

You may wish to see [an overview of GUI technologies available in Qt 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19105395/1329652), to see how Qt Quick 1 fits in.