# clang fails to link against Qt 5.1.1 frameworks on Mac OS X

Tags: qt, clang, clang++

I've Qt 5.1.1 installed in '/Users/me/lib/qt-5.1.1/'. Under '/Users/me/lib/qt-5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib' there are all frameworks but building a simple application:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <qapplication.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);

   QMainWindow mw;
   mw.show();

   return app.exec();
}
```

after canonical steps:

```
 $qmake -project
 $qmake
 $make
```

linker fails to link:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "QMainWindow::QMainWindow(QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>)", referenced from:
     _main in main.o
 "QMainWindow::~QMainWindow()", referenced from:
     _main in main.o
 "QApplication::exec()", referenced from:
    _main in main.o
 "QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int)", referenced from:
    _main in main.o
 "QApplication::~QApplication()", referenced from:
    _main in main.o
 "QWidget::show()", referenced from:
    _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [test.app/Contents/MacOS/test] Error 1
```

I added to linker flags

```
-F/Users/me/lib/qt-5.1.1/5.1.1/clang_64/lib -framework QtGui -framework QtCore
```

clang version is:

```
$clang --version
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.27) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project generated by qmake likely doesn't include the `widgets` module.

Please inspect your `.pro` file. You do *not* need to add those framework linker flags manually. Simply add your modules to the QT variable:

```
QT += widgets
```

Qmake has a dependency resolution mechanism, so if you add the widgets module, the `core` and `gui` modules will be pulled in automatically.

Do note that `widgets` is a new module in Qt 5. In Qt 4, `QWidget` hierarchy was a part of the `gui` module. It has been separated out, creating a lightweight `gui` module. My [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19105395/1329652) explains what kinds of GUI frameworks are offered in Qt 5.

Comment: Thank you, it works...i did't know about new module 'widgets'. I supposed that 'gui' and 'core' were sufficient. However i see these two modules are pulled in automatically also without specifing 'widgets' module in '.pro' file.