# Using QML for creating curses applications

Tags: c++, c, qml, ncurses, qt-quick

There's a presentation ([video](http://youtu.be/pTSPviWQs4w), [slides](http://devdays.kdab.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/QtDevDays-2013-FastUIPrototyping.pdf)) that demonstrates the use of QML in developing *ncurses* applications.

I've searched everywhere, but I couldn't find any documentation on the subject, does anyone have any idea on how to achieve what was done in the presentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt can be ([Ncurses and Qt Interoperability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606318/ncurses-and-qt-interoperability)) used to handle the async I/O details of an ncurses app even without QML nor any other high-level frameworks.

You could also expose some C++ class framework for text interfaces via QML. For example, as was done in the presentation, you could expose [CDK - the Curses Development Kit](http://invisible-island.net/cdk/) to QML.

I couldn't find the code from the presentation, but re-implementing it shouldn't be too hard. All you do is wrap CDK objects in QObjects, properly exposing the properties as Qt properties.